# Email regex validation that does not allow email's to end in .mil

Tags: regex, validation, email-validation

I am trying to find/write a regex that does not allow the email address to end in .mil when input into a form.

This is what I have to allow ONLY emails ending in .mil, but in this instance I would like the opposite. My understanding of RegEx is amateur at best:

```
^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.mil)$
```

Thanks! If you're willing, a break down of the different pieces or the change would be very helpful so I understand better moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind at the end.

```
^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(?<!\.mil)$
```

Comment: for some reason when I put this regex into VSCode I get an error and it will not parse the email validation. It seems to "not like" the negative lookbehind.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: JavaScript. However I think I've determined that it SHOULD be working, but it's our internal software not allowing it to do so.